# How to get the value of a dropdown menu in the admin interface?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

Does anybody know how to get the selected item of a dropdown menu from within a clean method in a modelform object, before the object has been saved? I have tried the following:

```
def clean_something(self):
   dropdown = self.cleaned_data.get('dropdown')
```

where 'dropdown' is the field representing the dropdown menu, but this doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Charles

Comment: What does `self.cleaned_data['dropdown']` give you? The selected index?

Comment: Thanks Dominic, I think I overlooked a small detail here... It seems that cleaned_data works fine, I just forgot to convert it to unicode!

Answer (score 0):

You will find it in,  self.data

```
def clean_something(self):
   dropdown = self.data.get('dropdown')
```

Comment: Thanks harshh, but self.data.get gives me the primary key, and not the value that's shown in the dropdown menu. Of course I can do a lookup, but I was wondering if there is an easier way to get the value straight from the form.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guys, I should have tested this more thoroughly... The following gives me the value I was looking for!

```
def clean_something(self):
   dropdown = u'%s' % self.cleaned_data.get('dropdown')
```